# Copy external image to server with PHP

Tags: php, image, url, copy, external

I want to copy an external image to my local server.
I know how to do it when the url looks like this: www.external.com/image.jpg
But how does it work when the image is like this: www.external.com/image.php?image=flower ?

The code I have is this:

```
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);

$type = $headers["Content-Type"];
$types = array('image/gif' => 'gif', 'image/jpeg' => 'jpeg', 'image/png' => 'png');

if(in_array($type, $types))
{

 copy($url, '../img/'.$name.'.'.$types[$type]);

}
```

Answer:

Looks like the if(in_array($type, $types)) was the problem.
When I removed that part everything went smoothly.

Just tested with file_get_contentst() and fwrite() though.

Thanks for the advice guys!

Comment: What happens when you use this code on an url like `http://www.external.com/image.php?image=flower`?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The URL format really shouldn't matter so long as the correct headers and binary are being returned. Additionally, have you looked at using curl for file transfer?

Comment: Nothing happens, the code just doesn't work, copy(..) gives a false. No I haven't looked at curl yet, but maybe it's in the copy()? Can I use another function for that?

Comment: Update: If I use file_get_contents() and fwrite() instead of copy() it doesn't work either..

Comment: Looks like the if(in_array($type, $types)) was the problem.
When I removed that part everything went smoothly. 

Just tested with file_get_contentst() and fwrite() though.

Thanks for the advice guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you generating the `$name` value.  If you are pulling that from the URL, perhaps there is an issue with how you are creating the `$name` value.

Also, have you tried escaping the URL string you provide to the copy command?  Just to ensure that it's not the URL string that is causing the problem.

Comment: I already tested without the $name value. That wasn't the problem. Didn't try escaping the url string, good advice!